# Moment of inertia of hollow cone

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $S$ be the boundary of the solid cone $x^2 + y^2 < z^2<2$ in the upper half of the $xyz$-space. Assume that $\mathcal S$ has constant density equal to $3$. Determine the moment of inertia with respect to the $z$-axis of the surface $\mathcal S$.

My solution is as follows:

$$I_z = \iint_S 3r^2 dS = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt 2} 3 z^2 (\sqrt{2}z)\, \mathrm d z \, \mathrm d \theta=6 \sqrt 2 \pi $$

However on Wikipedia it says the moment of inertia of a hollow cone is $I_z = \frac 1 2 m r^2$ which would give $I_z = 2 \sqrt 2 \pi$

Which answer is right?

Answer (score 2):

Your first answer is the correct one. The surface area of a right cone (minus its base) of radius $r$ and altitude $h$ is $\pi r\sqrt{r^2+h^2}$. In this case, $r=h=\sqrt{2}$ and we get $S = 2\pi\sqrt{2}$, so $m=6\pi\sqrt{2}$ and thus $I_z = 6\pi\sqrt{2}$.

As for what went wrong: You probably found the mass of the corresponding solid cone in your second calculation. If $3$ were volumetric density instead of surface density, the formula $V = \pi r^2h/3$ gives $m=2\pi\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I think you're saying that if the correct mass is plugged into the Wikipedia formula then the correct answer comes out. (This is true.)

Comment: Yes, I was being diagnostic with the second statement. I'll edit it to make this more clear.

Comment: oh of course! thank you.